# linenfile Ansible module doesn't insert all lines as expected

Tags: linux, ansible

I am trying to print a few lines to a file of each target host. However, the lines are missing from the file. This means, my hostlist file has about 10 servers. I get lines only for 8 sometimes or 6 and so on. The missing lines concerning hosts are entirely random. Below are the few lines from code, `Redhatx.Kernel` is coming from vars_file.

The verbose mode does show a line added for the missing hosts when I check. Wondering what I am missing, any hunches, please?

```yaml
     - name: Run patch status check
        set_fact:
           patch_state: success
        when:
          - ansible_distribution == "RedHat"
          - (facter_kernelrelease == "{{ Redhat6.Kernel }}" or
             facter_kernelrelease == "{{ Redhat7.Kernel }}" or
             facter_kernelrelease == "{{ Redhat8.Kernel }}")
        register: result

      - name: Patch status
        set_fact:
           patch_state: Failed
        when:  result is skipped

      - name: CSV - Get the facts
        set_fact:
          csv_tmp: >
            {{ ansible_fqdn }},{{ ansible_distribution }},{{ ansible_distribution_version }},{{ patch_state }}

      - name: CSV - Write information into .csv file
        lineinfile:
         insertafter: EOF
         dest: "{{ output_path }}/{{ filename }}"
         line: "{{ csv_tmp }}"
        state: present
        delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: Ansible runs multiple hosts simultanously, so it could happen that one task overwrites changes by another. You could try to use `serial: 1` for the playbook, but IIRC there is a better solution than lineinfile for this. I'll see if I can find the answer again.

Comment: Notice you can always recall facts for *any* host that is included into the run, not only for the current host. This is described in the [Ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#id5) and invoked like this: `{{ hostvars['asdf.example.com']['ansible_facts']['os_family'] }}`.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid concurrent writing to a file. There are more options.

- The simplest one is to set [*throttle*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#task) to 1. For example,

```yaml
    - name: CSV - Write information into .csv file
      lineinfile:
        insertafter: EOF
        dest: "{{ output_path }}/{{ filename }}"
        line: "{{ _line|join(',') }}"
        state: present
      delegate_to: localhost
      throttle: 1
      vars:
        _line:
          - "{{ ansible_fqdn }}"
          - "{{ ansible_distribution }}"
          - "{{ ansible_distribution_version }}"
          - "{{ patch_state }}"
```

- The more efficient option is [running the task only once](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html) and iterating [*ansible_play_hosts*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#magic-variables). For example,

```yaml
    - name: CSV - Write information into .csv file
      lineinfile:
        insertafter: EOF
        dest: "{{ output_path }}/{{ filename }}"
        line: "{{ _line|join(',') }}"
        state: present
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      vars:
        _line:
          - "{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_fqdn'] }}"
          - "{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_distribution'] }}"
          - "{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_distribution_version'] }}"
          - "{{ hostvars[item]['patch_state'] }}"
```